# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'mock') in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js line 395737

Tags: karma-jasmine

I have written a test case in angular using jasmin and karma.
The test cases runs fine in master branch on local however it fails in its subBranch.
what could be the difference between master and its subbranch that's causing this error?
I have also merged my subbranch with master.
[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vgKv.png)
[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLohc.png)

tried running specific test case using fdescribe method to see if its causing error because of other test cases.
npm install to see if its because of dependency issue.
created different branch and ran same code without any error.
changes angular cli version.